# How to set initial focus of textbox on page load using knockoutjs

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js

I'm having trouble setting the initial focus to a textbox on page load  when using knockout.  When I try to set the focus using the knockout attribute "hasfocus" it does nothing.  When I call the jQuery function focus again it does nothing.

I've found that if I remove the applyBindings call my jQuery works.  So it does seem to be something with knockout is interfering with the textbox getting focus.

My input textbox looks like this:

```
<input id="txtShippingLine" type="text" class="TextBox" data-bind="hasfocus: true, value: shipToNumber, enterKeySubmit: getDetailedShippingLineAndProcess, tabKeySubmit: getDetailedShippingLineAndProcess" />
```

My jQuery to try to set focus looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#txtShippingLine').focus();
```

});

I have a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/fande455/6RMk3/

I've tried this in Chrome, Firefox, and IE with the same behavior on each one.

Update
So the jsFiddle is now working with all the javascript in one file.  However, I have an MVC view that is importing scripts as well as the _Layout.cshtml file is importing javascript with a document.ready() functions in each of these files.

The top of the  Index.html view file looks like this:

```
    @section JavaScript
{
   <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Model/ShippingLine.js")"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Model/DetailedShippingLine.js")"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Model/ShippedPackage.js")"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Model/PackageDetail.js")"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Model/Address.js")"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/ViewModel/Index.js")"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#txtShippingLine').focus();
            viewModel.getShippedPackages();
            ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
        });

        // create a function for getting the root path 
        $.url = function (url) {
            var path = '@Request.ApplicationPath'
            if (path != '/') path = path + '/'
            return path + url;
        };

        var viewModel = new IndexViewModel();
    </script>
}

<div class="ConfirmationDialog">
    <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float: left; margin: 0 7px 20px 0;"></span>This shipment will be permanently deleted and cannot be recovered. Are you sure?</p>
</div>

<div id="Loading" data-bind="visible: loading()">
    <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/loading.gif")" alt="Now Loading..." />
</div> 

<div id="IndexxTabs" data-bind="jQueryUITabs: true, tab3show: getShippedPackages, visible: loading() != true" class="Tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Ship</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Find Shipping Lines</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Recent Shipments</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab" id="tabs-1">
        <h1>Ship</h1>
        <div class="ui-state-error ui-corner-all" style="padding: 4px" data-bind="text: tab1ErrorMessage, visible: tab1ErrorMessage().length > 0"></div>
        <div id="textboxWrapper" data-bind="visible: !detailedShippingLine().Id">
            <input id="txtShippingLine" type="text" class="TextBox" data-bind="hasFocus: setFocus, value: shipToNumber, enterKeySubmit: getDetailedShippingLineAndProcess, tabKeySubmit: getDetailedShippingLineAndProcess" />
            <button data-bind="jQueryUIButton: true, click: getDetailedShippingLine" type="button">Ship</button>
        </div>
```

The top of the _Layout.cshtml file looks like the following:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
        <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/IndexxShip.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Themes/redmond/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-3.0.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/CustomBindings.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Libraries/moment.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
        @RenderSection("JavaScript", required: false)

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                //$(".Tabs").tabs();
                //$("button").button();
                $(".ConfirmationDialog").dialog({
                    resizable: false,
                    autoOpen: false,
                    width: 640,
                    height: 480,
                    modal: true
                });

            });
        </script>
    </head>
```

One of the scripts the _Layout.cshtml references is CustomBindings.js which looks like the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // A binding to apply jQueryUI Button to an element
    ko.bindingHandlers.jQueryUIButton = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
            $(element).button();
        }
    };

    // A binding to apply jQueryUI Button to an element,
    // and to allow enable / disable bindings
    ko.bindingHandlers.jQueryUIButtonEnabled = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
            $(element).button();
        },
        update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
            if (ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor())) {
                $(element).button("enable");
            } else {
                $(element).button("disable");
            };
        }
    };

    // For jQueryUI Tabs. Handles additional bindings tab1show, tab2show, and tab3show
    // These bindings take a function as their value, and when that tab is shown, this
    // binding invokes the function
    ko.bindingHandlers.jQueryUITabs = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
            $(element).tabs();
            var allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();
            $(element).bind('tabsshow', function (event, ui) {
                switch (ui.index) {
                    case 0:
                        if (allBindings.tab1show) {
                            allBindings.tab1show();
                        };
                        break;

                    case 1:
                        if (allBindings.tab2show) {
                            allBindings.tab2show();
                        };
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        if (allBindings.tab3show) {
                            allBindings.tab3show();
                        };
                        break;
                }
            });
        }
    };

    // A binding to attach the ENTER key to a form field
    ko.bindingHandlers.enterKeySubmit = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
            $(element).keyup(function (e) {
                if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    valueAccessor()();
                    return false;
                };
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: If you are using *hasFocus* binding than there is no need to call jquery *focus* function, *hasFocus* will do the trick.Check this fiddle http://jsbin.com/niqurilo/1/edit hasFocus is working properly.

Comment: So explain why hasfocus isn't working on my jsFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

I made a few changes to the position of the functions and I also combined your ready function.

Look for the <-- here tags i put. (Stack Overflow is making it impossible for me to post the jfiddle url so i just quoted the entire thing below. My appologies)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#txtShippingLine').focus(); // <-- here
    viewModel.getShippedPackages();
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

    // A binding to apply jQueryUI Button to an element
    ko.bindingHandlers.jQueryUIButton = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
            $(element).button();
        }
    };

    // A binding to apply jQueryUI Button to an element,
    // and to allow enable / disable bindings
    ko.bindingHandlers.jQueryUIButtonEnabled = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
            $(element).button();
        },
        update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
            if (ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor())) {
                $(element).button("enable");
            } else {
                $(element).button("disable");
            };
        }
    };

    // For jQueryUI Tabs. Handles additional bindings tab1show, tab2show, and tab3show
    // These bindings take a function as their value, and when that tab is shown, this
    // binding invokes the function
    ko.bindingHandlers.jQueryUITabs = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
            $(element).tabs();
            var allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();
            $(element).bind('tabsshow', function (event, ui) {
                switch (ui.index) {
                    case 0:
                        if (allBindings.tab1show) {
                            allBindings.tab1show();
                        };
                        break;

                    case 1:
                        if (allBindings.tab2show) {
                            allBindings.tab2show();
                        };
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        if (allBindings.tab3show) {
                            allBindings.tab3show();
                        };
                        break;
                }
            });
        }
    };

    ko.bindingHandlers.enterKeySubmit = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
            $(element).keyup(function (e) {
                if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    valueAccessor()();
                    return false;
                };
            });
        }
    };

    ko.bindingHandlers.tabKeySubmit = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
            $('body').keyup(function (e) {
                if (e.keyCode == 9) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    valueAccessor()();
                    return false;
                };
            });
        }
    };
});

// create a function for getting the root path <-- here
$.url = function (url) {
    var path = '@Request.ApplicationPath'
    if (path != '/') path = path + '/'
    return path + url;
}

var viewModel = new IndexViewModel(); <-- here
```

Comment: Did that fix the problem for you though?  I pasted your code into the jsfiddle with the same results.  The two document readys is not the issue.  That was there because I pasted code in from my other scripts for completeness.  And again, when I comment out the view model creation and the apply bindings code the focus works.

Comment: Yea, it did. it works in chrome, i.e. and firefox, i'll past the link now- http://jsfiddle.net/6RMk3/17/ - like someone said, your stuff doesn't appear to be running in the order you think it is.

Comment: Ok, it does fix it in jsfiddle now.  It wasn't refreshing before for some reason.  It does seem to be an order problem like you said.  The only issue I'm having now is those document readys are in multiple files being brought into the page.  I pasted them into the jsfiddle to get a working example.  I'm struggling now with splitting this javascript into multiple files, but still having the focus run at the correct time.

Comment: Ok, check this url out, http://jsfiddle.net/6RMk3/42/, it doesn't matter where I put it now. The original issue was that IndexViewModel was not instantiated and had no definition, so it was bombing out before it hit focus function. I believe this is the issue you are having, you are bombing out before running any code somewhere. Check your code and instantiations.

Answer (score 0):

Something is setting the focus away from your text field after knockout sets it, probably jquery tabs. Set it back asynchronously.

```
<input ... data-bind="hasFocus: initialFocus, ..." />
```

and in your javascript

```
viewModel.initialFocus = ko.observable(true)
$(document).ready(
  // doesn't need to be in its own doc.ready
  function(){setTimeout(function(){viewModel.initialFocus(true);},0);
});
```

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/6RMk3/45/)

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so you are not running things in the order which you think they are running. I'd suggest using something like https://github.com/DegreeDev/Registrar to register and run your files in the order they should be fun. For example, you have a bunch on $(document).ready which get fired when the document is ready, they are kicked off async, so the depending on when they finish things may not be in the spot where you think they are (you focus call at the bottom).

Answer (score -2):

Try use `.triggerHandler("focus")` instead of `.focus()`.

Comment: That does not fix it.

Comment: Its more a direction to look into. The focus event does not fire with just calling focus, also you have two document ready calls. I did see the focus call in both though.  A quick look at the [link](http://api.jquery.com/focus/) shows the reason for why.

Comment: The problem is not with jQuery.  Focus does work when knockout is not involved.  That's why I mentioned that in the question above.  Knockout seems to be interfering, and knockout's hasfocus does not work.